# get dates there is no overlapping between above dates

Tags: sql, recursion

```
event_id|event_start|event_end
A            1          10
B            2          11
C            5          15
D            9          12
E           10          13
F           11          20
G           14          22
H           15          22
I           17          27
J           22          27
```

I have a table like above mention but i need a expected output like this

Expected output:

```
event_id|event_start|event_end
A            1         10
E            10        13
G            14        22
J            22        27
```

Logic is there is no overlapping between the above dates

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Comment: Why wouldn't the output be (for example) B, F and J?

Comment: Because the event should be started after the previous event ends so, only

Answer (score 0):

You could sue a correlated subquery to get the ID of the next possible event. Then use a recursive CTE to successively add the next events by joining on that ID.

Here's an example how this would look like in Postgres:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte
AS
(
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT t2.event_id
               FROM elbat t2
               WHERE t2.event_start >= t1.event_end
               ORDER BY t2.event_start,
                        t2.event_id
               LIMIT 1) next_event_id
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE t1.event_id = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT t2.event_id
               FROM elbat t2
               WHERE t2.event_start >= t1.event_end
               ORDER BY t2.event_start,
                        t2.event_id
               LIMIT 1) next_event_id
       FROM elbat t1
            INNER JOIN cte c
                       ON c.next_event_id = t1.event_id
)
SELECT event_id,
       event_start,
       event_end
       FROM cte
       ORDER BY event_start;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=d28fadc252b59317184ce40faf173d96)